# Error Jquery for html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**Read before giving the answer**

This function does not work. 
I need equal to this company 
http://www.redehost.com.br/hospedagem-de-site/planos

When you select the period in case the value of this exchange will be the link and the content of the DIV
skype: benhur.augusto

**Must change by value or by id?**

```
<select name="select"  sourceindex="0">
<option value="1" >Mensal</option>                    
<option value="3" id="trimestral" >Trimestral (3% de desconto)</option>
<option value="6" id="Semestral" >Semestral (6% de desconto)</option>
<option value="12" >Anual (12% de desconto)
</option>
</select>


<div id="p01" class="price">$3.99 <i>/ por mês</i></div>
<div id="p02" class="price">$3.99 <i>/ por mês</i></div>
<div id="p03" class="price">$3.99 <i>/ por mês</i></div>
<div id="p04" class="price">$3.99 <i>/ por mês</i></div>

<a href="#"  id="l01" class="button orange small colorchan">Comprar Agora</a>
<a href="#"  id="l02" class="button orange small colorchan">Comprar Agora</a>
<a href="#"  id="l03" class="button orange small colorchan">Comprar Agora</a>
<a href="#"  id="l04" class="button orange small colorchan">Comprar Agora</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#trimestral").click(function() {
$("#p01").html("R$53.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
$("#p02").html("R$63.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
$("#p03").html("R$73.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
$("#p04").html("R$83.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
$("#l01").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
$("#l02").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
$("#l03").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
$("#l04").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
});


$("#semestral").click(function() {
$("#p01").html("R$93.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
$("#p02").html("R$103.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
$("#p03").html("R$113.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
$("#p04").html("R$123.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
$("#l01").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
$("#l02").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
$("#l03").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
$("#l04").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: posting a url to some site is not a replacement for a full explanation of what your code is expected to do, and what is the current problem you have. `Must change by value or id` is meaningless without more details

Comment: I need the function list/menu and change the values

Answer (score 2):

Use `.on('change',` on you `select` (not the `.click(` on the option), get the option `id`, then run your code based off the `id`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=select]').on('change', function(){
      var optionId = $(this).attr('id');
      if(optionId == 'trimestral'){
        ....
      }
      else if(optionId == 'semestral'){
        ....
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you try to trigger a click on a select-option.

You need to trigger the `onchange`-event of the select-field like this.

```
<select name="select"  sourceindex="0" id="idoftheselectfield">
<option value="1" >Mensal</option>                    
<option value="3" id="trimestral" >Trimestral (3% de desconto)</option>
<option value="6" id="Semestral" >Semestral (6% de desconto)</option>
<option value="12" >Anual (12% de desconto)</option>
</select>
```

jquery:

```
$("#idoftheselectfield").change(function() {
    var selectValue = $(this).val();
    if(selectValue == "6") {
        // put code for semestral
        $("#p01").html("R$53.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
        $("#p02").html("R$63.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
        $("#p03").html("R$73.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
        $("#p04").html("R$83.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
        $("#l01").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
        $("#l02").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
        $("#l03").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
        $("#l04").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");

    } else if(selectValue == "3") {
        // put code for trimestral

        $("#p01").html("R$93.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
        $("#p02").html("R$103.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
        $("#p03").html("R$113.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
        $("#p04").html("R$123.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
        $("#l01").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
        $("#l02").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
        $("#l03").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
        $("#l04").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
    }
});
```

Please note, that this is a pretty ugly concept doing what you probably want to achieve. But to your question - this is how you can handle the selection of the select-field.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write `change` event instead of `click` event for drop-down list:

### HTML:

```
<select name="select" id="dropDown" sourceindex="0">
    <option value="1">Mensal</option>
    <option value="3" id="trimestral">Trimestral (3% de desconto)</option>
    <option value="6" id="Semestral">Semestral (6% de desconto)</option>
    <option value="12">Anual (12% de desconto)</option>
</select>
<div id="p01" class="price">$3.99 <i>/ por mês</i>

</div>
<div id="p02" class="price">$3.99 <i>/ por mês</i>

</div>
<div id="p03" class="price">$3.99 <i>/ por mês</i>

</div>
<div id="p04" class="price">$3.99 <i>/ por mês</i>

</div>
<a href="#" id="l01" class="button orange small colorchan">Comprar Agora</a>

<a href="#" id="l02" class="button orange small colorchan">Comprar Agora</a>

<a href="#" id="l03" class="button orange small colorchan">Comprar Agora</a>

<a href="#" id="l04" class="button orange small colorchan">Comprar Agora</a>
```

### JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dropDown").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '3') { // check option selected option value is 3
            $("#p01").html("R$53.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#p02").html("R$63.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#p03").html("R$73.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#p04").html("R$83.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#l01").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
            $("#l02").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
            $("#l03").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
            $("#l04").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
        } else if ($(this).val() === '6') { // check if selected option value is 6
            $("#p01").html("R$93.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#p02").html("R$103.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#p03").html("R$113.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#p04").html("R$123.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#l01").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
            $("#l02").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
            $("#l03").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
            $("#l04").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
        }
    });
```

### DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/hf2ZU/

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to listen for the `change` event of your `select`tag and then analyse the selected option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name=select]").change(function() {
        if ($(this).find("option:selected").attr('id') == "trimestral") {
            $("#p01").html("R$53.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#p02").html("R$63.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#p03").html("R$73.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#p04").html("R$83.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#l01").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
            $("#l02").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
            $("#l03").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
            $("#l04").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
        } else if ($(this).find("option:selected").attr('id') == "Semestral") {

            $("#p01").html("R$93.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#p02").html("R$103.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#p03").html("R$113.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#p04").html("R$123.99 <i>/ por mês</i>");
            $("#l01").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
            $("#l02").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
            $("#l03").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
            $("#l04").attr("href", "http://www.codigosnaweb.com");
        }
});
});
```

### Here is a quick demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/6XHaG/